# How to hide axes and gridlines

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I would like to be able to hide the axes and gridlines on a 3D matplotlib graph. I want to do this because when zooming in and out the image gets pretty nasty. I'm not sure what code to include here but this is what I use to create the graph.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.view_init(30, -90)
ax.set_xlabel("X")
ax.set_ylabel("Y")
ax.set_zlabel("Z")
plt.xlim(0,pL)
plt.ylim(0,pW)
ax.set_aspect("equal")

plt.show()
```

This is an example of the plot that I am looking at:
[image: This is an example of the plot that I am looking at]

Answer (score 168, accepted):

```
# Hide grid lines
ax.grid(False)

# Hide axes ticks
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
ax.set_zticks([])
```

Note, you need matplotlib>=1.2 for `set_zticks()` to work.

Comment: just leaving this note here because it tripped me up a bit: If you are using pandas, for example `df.hist(...)`, make sure you call `ax.grid(False)` AFTER `df_hist(...)`

Answer (score 124):

Turn the axes off with:

```
plt.axis('off')
```

And gridlines with:

```
plt.grid(b=None)
```

Comment: Nice suggestion.

Comment: @johnnyh101 What if I had more than one ax, when using a subplot? How do I apply the above. Right now I have to either loop and set `ax[i].grid(False)` for each one of them. Is there a global command for subplots?

Comment: @AMerii `plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = False` will turn it off for all plots