# Why do white lines occur in my plt image?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a following problem. I plot an graph over a background image. Sometimes Spyder (my IDE) plots over the the image strange white horizontal and vertical lines. See graphs bellow.

This is what sometimes happens: [image]

Desired output: [image]

I use this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("./myimg.png")
plt.imshow(img)

x = mydata[['Centroid1']]
y = mydata[['Centroid2']]

scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, s=20, alpha=0.3, color='red')
plt.show()
```

Do you know, how can I delete these white lines?

Comment: Did you try to hide the grid with `ax.grid(False)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These white lines are the gridlines of you plot. I do not know why they appear but you can remove them with `ax.grid(False)`.

Also, possible duplicate of [How to hide axes and gridlines in Matplotlib (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45148704/how-to-hide-axes-and-gridlines-in-matplotlib-python).